# Making a typedef struct externally available in c++

Tags: c++, struct, extern

I think I'm doing something stupid, but I don't quite know what. I'm trying to rewrite a fairly simple library I have that is reading in some variables from a text file and then shares them with some other source files for use elsewhere. When I wanted to pass a double I was doing this:

```
#if !defined(SharedVariables_h)
#define SharedVariables_h

#include <vector>

extern double coeff_A;

#endif
```

and then doing this in both the source file where it was defined and the other source files where I want to use it:

```
#include "SharedVariables.h"
```

to make `coeff_A` available in the new source file.

But then my model got more complicated and I was using more coefficients so I decided to store them in a structure and pass that structure using `extern` instead. I created a new header file for the structure (`CParameters.h`):

```
#pragma once
#if !defined(CParameters_h)
#define CParameters_h

typedef struct
{
    int         coeff_A;
    int         coeff_B;
    double      coeff_C;
    double      coeff_D;

} SGlobalParameterData;


#endif
```

and then defined the struct like this:

```
#if !defined(SharedVariables_h)
#define SharedVariables_h

#include "CParameters.h"
#include <vector>

extern SGlobalParameterData globalParameters;

#endif
```

In the first source file where I read in all the values from the data files and using the values I've replaced:

```
#include "SharedVariables.h"


double coeff_A;
...
```

with

```
#include "SharedVariables.h"


SGlobalParameterData globalParameters;

globalParameters = readProperties(prefsFile);

....
```

In the second source file which also needs to use some of these variables I've added `#include "SharedVariables.h"` and then the IDE and compiler let me easily access `globalParameters.coeff_A`, `globalParameters.coeff_B`, etc.

I thought this should work and everything compiles without any errors, but it's not actually passing the values read into `globalParameters` to the second source file. Everything is just zero when I'm debugging the code.

So there are really two questions: 1) Is it possible to share structs using `extern` like for `double`, and 2) if it is, what have I done wrong.

Hopefully someone can point out my mistake.

### Edit

I've added in an line of code in my example to show the function that assigns the values to the struct. This is working and the values read from the `prefsFile` are available and correct in the f1rst source file, but these values are not passed to source file 2. I'm going to do some more testing because it appears I may have made some other mistake elsewhere.

Comment: It's perfectly possible (although globals are a bad idea in general) and the code you posted should work (as far as I can see). So I think the problem you have is caused by some other issue that's not obvious fom the code you have posted so far.

Comment: c++ needs no typedef for a struct

Comment: In short the answers are 1) Yes and 2) Not sure.

Comment: @eerorika, @rustyx      Thanks for the help. I think after reviewing the code in the rest of this library, it may be the case that my problem isn't sharing a struct between 2 files, but sharing a `stuct` between two different classes when it is created in one of those classes. Each class happens to be a separate file with both classes getting compiled to create one dll. I need to do some research on this and it seems like it's a completely different question I should be asking.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion stems from the use of `typedef` and mixing of declarations and definitions.

In C++ `typedef` isn't needed to define a `struct` type and is only confusing.

`typedef struct { ... } SGlobalParameterData;` - this declares a type `SGlobalParameterData` that is a `struct`. It defines no instance of the struct.

`struct SGlobalParameterData { ... };` - same thing, declares a type `SGlobalParameterData` that is a `struct`.

`struct { ... } globalParameterData;` - this defines an object `globalParameterData` of an unnamed `struct` type.

`struct SGlobalParameterData { ... } globalParameters;` - this defines an object `globalParameters` of an `struct` type called `SGlobalParameterData`.

So... the following might be most readable/clean IMHO:

In the header:

```
struct SGlobalParameterData   // type declaration
{
    int         coeff_A;
    int         coeff_B;
    double      coeff_C;
    double      coeff_D;
};

extern SGlobalParameterData globalParameters; // global instance *declaration*
```

In one of source files:

```
#include "the header above"

SGlobalParameterData globalParameters; // global instance *definition*
```

In other source files:

```
#include "the header above"

// globalParameters is already visible and usable
```

Of course you have to compile all source files and link them together into an executable.

Comment: This is all good advice but unless I'm missing something it doesn't capture the error that the OP is making.

Comment: Yes, this is good advice and it's a bit cleaner than what I had written, I've just tested the changes but it still doesn't resolve that all values in the struct in the second source file are all zero. It's looking like I may have some other problem

Comment: @jpmorr it should work. The issue must be elsewhere in your project, in the parts not shown. This is why it's important to make a [mcve]. Oftentimes the error fixes itself while making one :)

Comment: Since you're being pedantic about declaration and definition, what you've described as declaration of `SGlobalParameterData` is in fact a definition of that type (of course, definitions are also declarations).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to share structs using extern like for double

Yes.

> 2. if it is, what have I done wrong.

Something that you haven't shown to us.

> Everything is just zero

This is to be expected because variables with static storage are zero-initialised, and you never modify `globalParameters` in the example.

Here is your code running. Only change I made was to add some output, and actually set some other value than zero. That non-zero value works as expected: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CasO8c68W3FmBsQH

Comment: Thanks for your example. I've added the extra line of code showing where `globalParameters` is filled. As I mention, the function fills the `struct` in source file 1 and the values are available and I use them successfully, but when I try to get to `coeff_A` in source file 2, it is zero, despite having some specified value in source file 1.

Comment: @jpmorr You cannot have an assignment statement like that in namespace scope.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - `readProperties()` is returning a struct of type `SGlobalParameterData`. And I can use it everywhere in file 1 without a problem. So you think this is why everything stays zero?

Comment: @jpmorr I would expect you to see an error such as this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/adw9mkPbEiZBhcZX